# Spring Boot register JAX-WS webservice as bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, jax-ws

In my spring boot ws based application I have created a jax-ws webservice following a contract first approach. The Web service is up but I cannot autowire my other beans inside my webservice.

How can I define, my webservice in spring as bean?

Following is my webservice impl class:

```java
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.foo.bar.MyServicePortType")
@Service
public class MySoapService implements MyServicePortType {
    @Autowired
    private MyBean obj;

    public Res method(final Req request) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\nCALLING.......\n\n" + obj.toString()); //obj is null here
        return new Res();
    }
}
```

MyServicePortType is geneated by maven from wsdl file

When I call this service (via SoapUi) it gives `NullPointerException` as the MyBean object is not autowired.

Since my application is built on Spring boot, there is no xml file. Currently I have `sun-jaxws.xml` file with endpoint configuration. How can I do following configuration in spring boot application

```xml
<wss:binding url="/hello">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#helloWs"/>
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
```

Following is my `SpringBootServletInitializer` class:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WSApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jaxws() {
        final ServletRegistrationBean jaxws = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WSServlet(), "/jaxws");
        return jaxws;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new WSServletContextListener());
    }
}
```

Comment: Using CXF as perfollowing https://github.com/vanioinformatika/spring-boot-cxf-integration-example solved the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extending `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` is the recommended way to get beans injected for JAX-WS endpoint class, from current spring root web application context. However this does not work with **spring boot** as it's a bit different on [servlet context initialization](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-context-initializer).

#### Problem

`SpringBootServletInitializer.startup()` uses a custom `ContextLoaderListener` and does not pass the created application context to `ContextLoader`. Later when the object of JAX-WS endpoint class being initialized, `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` depends on `ContextLoader` to retrieve the current application context, and always get `null`.

```
public abstract class SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext rootAppContext = createRootApplicationContext(
                servletContext);
        if (rootAppContext != null) {
            servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootAppContext) {
                @Override
                public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
                    // no-op because the application context is already initialized
                }
            });
        }
        ......
    }
}
```

#### Workaround

You could register a bean that implements `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializer` to retrieve the application context during `startup()`.

```
@Configuration
public class WebApplicationContextLocator implements ServletContextInitializer {

    private static WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    public static WebApplicationContext getCurrentWebApplicationContext() {
        return webApplicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    }
}
```

Then you could implement self-autowiring in your JAX-WS endpoint class.

```
@WebService
public class ServiceImpl implements ServicePortType {

    @Autowired
    private FooBean bean;

    public ServiceImpl() {
        AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bpp = new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
        WebApplicationContext currentContext = WebApplicationContextLocator.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
        bpp.setBeanFactory(currentContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
        bpp.processInjection(this);
    }

    // alternative constructor to facilitate unit testing.
    protected ServiceImpl(ApplicationContext context) {
        AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bpp = new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
        bpp.setBeanFactory(new DefaultListableBeanFactory(context));
        bpp.processInjection(this);
    }
}
```

#### Unit Testing

In unit tests you could get current spring application context injected, and call alternative constructor with it.

```
@Autowired 
private ApplicationContext context;

private ServicePortType service;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.service = new ServiceImpl(this.context);
}
```

Comment: After spending the whole day I found your great solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default Spring doesn't know anything about your JAX-WS endpoints – they're managed by the JAX-WS runtime rather than Spring. You can overcome this by using [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html) You'd typically do so simply by subclassing it:

```java
public class MySoapService extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements MyServicePortType {
    …
}
```

You also have the option of calling it directly from a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`:

```java
public class MySoapService implements MyServicePortType {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried both ways but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Using CXF as perfollowing github.com/vanioinformatika/spring-boot-cxf-integration-example solved the issue.

Comment: @wilkinson, this is not working in sring-boot 1.4, it is working with the approach specified by Parker, is there any standard solution to this?

Comment: Here we are talking about SPRING-BOOT but for this, we have to use this approach https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.embedded-container

 SpringBeanAutowiringSupport - should work for SRING but not for SpringBoot - for last one I used 

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jaxWsServletBean() {
        var bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new JaxWsServlet(), JaxWsServlet.URL_PATTERN);
        bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return bean;
    }

Comment: but I still have SOME PROBLEMS with 

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean jaxWsListenerBean() {
        var bean = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<WSServletContextListener>();
        bean.setListener(new WSServletContextListener());
        return bean;
    }

Answer (score 1):

You don´t have to extend your Configuration from SpringBootServletInitializer, nor override configure() or onStartup() methods. And in no way you have to build something implementing WebApplicationInitializer. There are only few steps to do (you could also do all the steps in a seperate @Configuration-class, the class with @SpringBootApplication only needs to know, where this one is - e.g. via @ComponentScan).

1. Register the CXFServlet in an ServletRegistrationBean
2. Instantiate a SpringBus
3. Instantiate your Implementation of the JAX-WS SEI (Service Interface)
4. Instantiate a EndpointImpl with the SpringBus and SEI implementing Beans
5. Call publish() method on that EndpointImpl

Done.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleBootCxfApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleBootCxfApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/soap-api/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }    

    @Bean
    public WeatherService weatherService() {
        return new WeatherServiceEndpoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), weatherService());
        endpoint.publish("/WeatherSoapService");
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively with the https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter you can spare yourself No. 1 & 2 - full description here: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/10/spring-boot-apache-cxf-spring-boot-starter/

Comment: This solution must be endorsed officially.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look this way: @ServletComponentScan

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ServletComponentScan
public class TelecomApplication { .... }
```

Answer (score -1):

Taking clue from @Andy Wilkinson using [SpringBeanAutoWiringSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html) is achieved by using

```java
public class MySoapService extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements MyServicePortType {
    …
}
```

You also have the option of calling it directly from a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`:

```java
@Service
public class MySoapService implements MyServicePortType {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
            servletContext);
    }
}
```